# Is there a "staging" or "test" environment for Canonical Livepatch?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I would like to create an Ansible role for the Canonical Livepatch service. Part of this process is to write "unit tests" for the role that would run in a CI/CD environment to verify that the role is working as intended.

The problem is that I can not find any documentation about "test" or "dry-run" capabilities of the Livepatch service.

Best case scenario would be to allow users to configure a "staging" or "testing" endpoint so that subsequent calls of `canonical-livepatch enable` would not result in a "live" registration of the server.

In theory I could run `canonical-livepatch disable` after my tests ran, but this would mean that one of my three free tokens is tied up for unit testing, which I'd like to avoid.

Does anyone have any information on how I can test the Livepatch service in my Ansible role?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```

is the best I could find

As described here:
["kernel-upgrade-required" is not one of applied, apply-failed, unapplied, needs-check, nothing-to-apply, unknown, check-failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066617/kernel-upgrade-required-is-not-one-of-applied-apply-failed-unapplied-needs)

So you might also do this

```
sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

and repeat it with 
    `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`
once more